# How do I update an HTML element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a button which opens a popup :

```
var RowView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .my-transaction-grid span.my-icon-export' : 'myExport',
    },
    myExport: function(){
        var uniqueKey = this.model.get('uniqueKey');
        var initSubmitButton = function(){
            $("#submitButton").on('click', function(response, postdata){
                window.open('downloadFile.action?uniqueKey=' + key + "&$myFolder=" + $("#myFolder").val(), '_self');
            });
        };

        var callback = function(){
            initSubmitButton(uniqueKey);
            initPaginationGrid("myGrid", "foldersForm", uniqueKey, true, null, "folderPopup.action", initSubmitButton);
        };
        loadPopupEdit("folderPopup.action", {uniqueKey: uniqueKey, editMode: true}, callback);
```

The popup is a jsp file, containing a dropdown list from which I can select a value :

```
<div id="POPUP-CONTENT" class="my-container-popup">
    <s:form id="foldersForm">
        <div class="my-content">
            <table class="my-table">
                <tr>
                    <td class="my-field><s:select id="myFolder" name="myFolder" list="myFoldersList" listKey="code" listValue="value" emptyOption="true" tabindex="3"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </s:form>
</div>
```

How can I get the updated value of `$("myFolder")`, when I have selected a value from the dropdown list, in the script where I call `window.open()` ?

What I am getting :

downloadFile.action?uniqueKey=ir8ej38&myFolder=

What I'd like to get :

downloadFile.action?uniqueKey=ir8ej38&myFolder=selectedFolder

Comment: What do you get instead? Do you mean getting the text from the option selected? Note that text might be different than value in a select field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out, should have used

```
window.open('downloadFile.action?uniqueKey=' + key + "&$myFolder=" + $("#myFolder :selected").text(), '_self');
```

instead of

```
window.open('downloadFile.action?uniqueKey=' + key + "&$myFolder=" + $("#myFolder").val(), '_self');
```